# Reading xml failing due to size -can it be read line by line in python?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

The following python code works fine when I use it on a test dataset of a few thousand records but when I try it with an xml of about 400MB it runs out of memory. Is there a way to get it to read line by line?

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = raw_input('Enter - ')

value,count,total, counts =0,0,0, dict()

print "Retrieving: ", url
file=urllib.urlopen(url)
data=file.read()
print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'
xml=ET.fromstring(data)
tags=xml.findall('.//Postcode')
for tag in tags:
#    print tag.text
    count+=int(tag.text)
print 'Count: ', len(tags)
print 'Sum: ', count
```

This will write to sqlite3 but fails with a memory error on testing (before it gets to the DB writing process that's not included in the sample code above).

The data I am trying to read can be freely downloaded from http://data.gov.au/dataset/abn-bulk-extract

Comment: Your first problem is this: `data=file.read()`.  That is where you are reading the entire result into memory.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#pull-api-for-non-blocking-parsing , and it references [iterparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse).  It looks like you can pass the file-like object returned from urlopen to ElementTree.iterparse() to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Which part have failed? The file.read() or ET.fromstring?

Easy solution (besides buying more memory) would be to save the retrieved file and use ET.parse(filename) to avoid reading the XML as a string to memory.

Other case is to use xml.sax API, which don't parse XML at the same time.

Comment: The "print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'" works so it is failing after this. I get an out of memory error. I have 16GB RAM and at least 500GB free on my drives so...It is reading the file off my hard drive (so I have already downloaded it)

Comment: when I try "xml=ET.parse(url)" I get   
>>File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 653, in parse
    data = source.read(65536)
MemoryError

The issue is trying to consume the dataset line by line or I guess finding a way to chunk into a couple of pieces of 50Mb each...